# .NET framework System.Windows.Form on non Windows OS

Tags: c#, .net, linux

So, I **MUST** use C# for a uni course, just like I **MUST** use MSSQL Server, the big problem is that I'm running Ubuntu. I followed [this](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/ubuntu16-04) guide, I mean it's from microsoft right? Can't get any of System.Windows.Form working, neither SqlDataAdapter and many more(like 99.65% of the libraries).
Anyone encountered this issue before? Or you just created a VM and waited a week for Visual to install?

This is what I get when I run `dotnet run`

```
Program.cs(4,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/potra/Desktop/School/School/DBMS/Test/Test.csproj]
Program.cs(8,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Form' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/potra/Desktop/School/School/DBMS/Test/Test.csproj]
Program.cs(10,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataGridView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/potra/Desktop/School/School/DBMS/Test/Test.csproj]
Program.cs(11,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataGridView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/potra/Desktop/School/School/DBMS/Test/Test.csproj]
Program.cs(12,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SqlDataAdapter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/potra/Desktop/School/School/DBMS/Test/Test.csproj]

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest .NET Core, 2.1 Preview 2, [does not include System.Windows.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.1&term=system.windows).

If you'd like to use a native Ubuntu runtime, [Mono supports WinForms](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) and [SqlClient](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlclient/).

For more information, [the .NET documentation explains how .NET is implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/components#net-implementations).